# Short for "common wishes that everybody says she has?"

Tags: translation

A friend is looking for a translation of his album title to English. The title in Persian roughly means "slogan wishes" if split apart and translated word by word. The actual meaning is "wishes that everybody chants like a slogan but most neither work towards nor achieve." What would you call it in English?

Comment: Things like *a cure for cancer, eternal life, an end to world hunger* come to mind. Ironically, we've made some progress on that last one, only to replace it with an increasing global obesity problem.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well I'm not really looking for examples of it, but rather a general word or a short phrase that incompasses such wishes, if there was any.

Comment: I just put them up as examples of humanity's "collective ambitions", thinking that might inspire someone to come up with a general term. But they don't really apply on the personal level (in practice, there's not much most people *could* do to further those goals). But we could certainly get closer to the second goal (by each living longer *as individuals*) if we all adopted healthier lifestyles, diets, etc. Sadly, I think in the US in particular, things are actually going *backwards* on that front (life expectancy is actually going *down* for middle-aged white American males, I believe).

Comment: (I can't think of a single word or short well-known expression for what you want to identify, obviously.)

Comment: @StoneyB: Or [**pious hopes**,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pious+hopes%22) perhaps. That usually implies ambitions *unlikely to be fulfilled* (because as we all know, *if wishes were horses, beggars would ride*).

Comment: @StoneyB "pious hopes" looks convincing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an idiom for: "a list of things that you know will not be completed but you are asking anyway"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336058/is-there-an-idiom-for-a-list-of-things-that-you-know-will-not-be-completed-but)

Comment: "wishful thinking" ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consider calling them *platitudes*.

> **platitude** *noun*
> A remark or statement, especially one with a moral content, that has been used too often to be interesting or thoughtful.
> ‘she began uttering liberal platitudes’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/platitude)
>
> A platitude is a trite, meaningless, or prosaic statement, generally directed at quelling social, emotional, or cognitive unease. Platitudes are geared towards presenting a shallow, unifying wisdom over a difficult topic. However, they are too general and overused to be anything more than undirected statements with ultimately little meaningful contribution towards a solution.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platitude)

Comment: This one does it for me! When I proposed ***pious hopes*** as a compound noun in an earlier comment, I didn't really think there would be a single-word term. But I note that [***pious platitudes***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pious+platitudes%22) gets nearly as many hits in Google Books - and when I stop to think about it, it seems to me ***pious*** is invariably *implied* anyway, so I think you've nailed this question on the "one-word answer" front.

Comment: The answer is spot on, so +1, but would I also suggest it as the title of a pop album? Hmm... it's definitely shorter than the OP's title though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why not? [Rolling Stone's top-ranked album of 2017](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/lists/20-best-pop-albums-of-2017-w513516/sam-smith-the-thrill-of-it-all-w513520) is "Melodrama", with "Rainbow" and "Reputation" coming 2nd and 3rd - all single word titles. "Platitudes" sounds pretty evocative. Maybe I'll make use of it. Even here: *Platitudes ... by ELU* hmm, seems fitting, somehow. :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Punning is the lowest form of wit, but I can certainly imagine an album being called ***[Im]pious plattertudes***. And I did find [Category Archives: Plattertudes. CDs, Tapes and Vinyl reviewed!](https://rocketlaunchingcapabilities.wordpress.com/category/plattertudes-cds-tapes-and-vinyl-reviewed/) on WordPress.

Comment: This doesn't *quite* work for me; when I think of platitudes, I think of some bromide that suggests that a problem has already been solved or will solve itself, rather than a statement of hope or ambition about solving the problem. In other words, something like "you look fine the way you are" rather than "my New Year's resolution is to lose weight," or "humans are adaptable" rather than "we should solve global warming."

Answer (score 16):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lip%20service):

> ### lip service
>
> *noun*
>   an avowal of advocacy, adherence, or allegiance **expressed in words but not backed by deeds** —usually used with *pay*

Similarly from [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lip%20service):

> Verbal expression of agreement or allegiance, **unsupported by real conviction or action**; hypocritical respect.
>
> *Lip service continues to be paid to resolving regional conflicts, but there is no sense of urgency* (Henry A. Kissinger).

And most pithily from [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lip_service):

> **an expression of agreement that is not supported by real conviction**

Some relevant synonyms [given by Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lip%20service) include:

- empty talk
- hollow words
- hypocrisy
- insincerity
- jive
- sham
- smooth talk
- sweet talk
- token agreement / tokenism¹

---

¹ <sub>In the *[only making a symbolic effort](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tokenism)* sense, not in the sense specific to affirmative-action or similar law.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

While the previous answers are quite good, I would also suggest you consider **pipe dreams**:

> an illusory or fantastic plan, ***hope***, or story
>
> Example: His plan for starting his own business was just a *pipe dream*.
>
> Synonyms: conceit, daydream, delusion, illusion, fantasy
>
> Related words: mirage, concoction, fable, fabrication, fiction, invention
>
> Definition of pipe dream for English Language Learners: a hope, wish, or dream that is impossible to achieve or not practical

Source: Merriam-Webster

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on the "nobody is doing anything about them" part, you may describe them as ***[idle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idle)*** wishes:

> *(adjective)*
>   3 : not based on anything real or serious • *an idle threat*
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idle)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This word carries a lot of specific connotations that your friend probably don't want for his/her album, but the (quite new) idea of *[slacktivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slacktivism)* could be fairly well described that way.